# JavaScript keydown event e.shiftKey + e.keyCode 8 asterisk

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project for school and I'm writing a calculator.
I got to the point where I'm programming the keydown event, the numbers aren't causing any problems, but I got stuck at the %, * and +.

The output I receive in the console.log is correct - I'm getting the asterisk * each time I press shift + 8, not when I press shift or 8 individually. But what I'm getting in the #output.innerHTML is " *8 ", since I also have an event listener for number 8, as seen above.

```
function forDisplay(value) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += value;
 
    }

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
 if(event.keyCode === 56 || event.keyCode === 104){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += 8
    }

 if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 56){    
        console.log('*')
        forDisplay('*')
    }

})
```

Is there any way I can make the code work in the output too, since it's working correctly in the console.log?
Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly related, but isn't a calculator much easier to implement without realtime validation, parse the entered string when a specific enter character is entered (ex. '=').

Comment: Say the logic out loud, it often helps to spot simple mistakes. (0) If keyCode is 56 or if keyCode is 104, then add an "8" (1) if keyCode is 56, then add an asterisk. You've satisfied two conditions. Huh? Wouldn't it be better to check for keyCode 56, if found, check the shift. Pressed? Asterisk. Not Pressed? 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem - the first `if` is firing, and so is the second `if` when you press Shift and 8. Simply check for the Shift and 8 first, then add an `else if` statement, in case the condition is not true.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 56) {
    console.log('*')
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "*";
  } else if (event.keyCode === 56 || event.keyCode === 104) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += 8
  }

})
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Also, here's my attempt at a calculator, complete with regular numbers, addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponent, Num Pad, designated symbols for multiplication and division, prevention for operands next to each other (things like `132+*837`), backspace, clearing options, and evaluation for Enter key, equal to, or `Evaluate` button:

```js
var outputEl = document.getElementById("output")

function CheckLastChar() {
  if (["×", "+", "-", "÷", "^"].includes(outputEl.innerText.slice(-1))) {
    outputEl.innerText = outputEl.innerText.slice(0, -1)
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    if (key == "8") {
      CheckLastChar();
      outputEl.innerText += "×";
    } else if (key == "6") {
      CheckLastChar();
      outputEl.innerText += "^";
    } else if (event.keyCode == 187) {
      CheckLastChar();
      outputEl.innerText += "+";
    }
  } else {
    if ([...Array(10).keys()].map(el => el.toString()).includes(key)) {
      outputEl.innerText += key;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 106) {
      CheckLastChar();
      outputEl.innerText += "×";
    } else if (event.keyCode == 107) {
      CheckLastChar();
      outputEl.innerText += "+";
    } else if (event.keyCode == 189 || event.keyCode == 109) {
      CheckLastChar();
      outputEl.innerText += "-";
    } else if (event.keyCode == 191 || event.keyCode == 111) {
      CheckLastChar();
      outputEl.innerText += "÷";
    } else if (event.keyCode == 8) {
      outputEl.innerText = outputEl.innerText.slice(0, -1);
    } else if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].click();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 187) {
      document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].click();
    }
  }
})

document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
  stringToEvaluate = document.getElementById("output").innerText.replace("×", "*").replace("÷", "/").replace("^", "**");
  console.clear();
  try {
    console.log(eval(stringToEvaluate));
  } catch {
    console.log("Unexpected error or invalid expression.");
  }
})

document.querySelectorAll("button")[1].addEventListener("click", () => {
  outputEl.innerText = "";
})
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<button>Evaluate!</button>
<button>Clear!</button>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do her/his homework. Your first part, before "here's my attempt at a calculator", answers the question; that's enough.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just noticed it while rereading it. I'll make sure to be more vigilant next time.